# Scheduling a composed task with arguments

Tags: spring-cloud-dataflow

I have those two tasks defined in Spring Cloud Dataflow, for sake of simplicity I'll simply call them `first-task` and `second-task`. Then I define a composed task:

```
task create --name my-composed-task --definition "first-task && second-task"
```

Now, I need to schedule this task, but I need that the scheduled task starts with two arguments, let's say that those arguments are `OBJECT_TYPES=1` and `SKIP_EXTRA_STUFF=true`. So I try to setup my schedule:

```
task schedule create --definitionName my-composed-task --name my-scheduled-task --expression '0 5 4 * ?' --arguments 'OBJECT_TYPES=1 SKIP_EXTRA_STUFF=true'
```

But when the schedule starts, the second task fails because those arguments are mandatory. I also tried to change the schedule definition like this:

```
task schedule create --definitionName my-composed-task --name my-scheduled-task --expression '0 5 4 * ?' --arguments "--composed-task-arguments='OBJECT_TYPES=1 SKIP_EXTRA_STUFF=true'"
```

but still the arguments are not passed across children tasks. Can someone tell me what's wrong with those definitions?

Answer (score 0):

For Composed Tasks, you can pass the arguments to the child tasks using the property key `--composedTaskArguments`. For instance,

you can do something like this:

```
task schedule create --definitionName my-composed-task --name my-scheduled-task --expression '0 5 4 * ?' --arguments "--composedTaskArguments=\"OBJECT_TYPES=1 SKIP_EXTRA_STUFF=true\""
```

Also, note that the values specified by `--composedTaskArguments` are passed to all the child tasks. The ability to pass the arguments to a specific child task of a composed task [has just been added](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-dataflow/issues/3919) to SCDF as well.

Comment: So... does it mean that I have to updated my SCDF to the latest version?

Comment: Still not working... in the log I see that the arguments are reported like this ["--composedTaskArguments=OBJECT_TYPES=1;2,SKIP_EXTRA_STUFF=true"] and then they are not forwarded to child task.

Comment: By the way: I'm using scheduler-task-launcher 2.4.0 and SCDF 2.4.0

Comment: Not sure if it's a bug. I tried it on 2.5.1. Is it possible for you try SCDF 2.5.1 which has got a few issues addressed around this?